# Domino Data Services REST get Database title?

Tags: rest, xpages, lotus-domino

I'm trying to get the title of a database whose URL I know via Domino Data Services. I only know it's filepath.

The only way I can think of right now is calling

```
GET http://server:80/api/data
```

and looping through all the entries. Isn't there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write a custom rest service where you post the file path/name and have it return the db title?

Comment: Not aware of DDS having that API. I never use DDS, don't like all that information that is not needed...and you expose everything in the database when you turn it on. The REST Service in the XPages extension lib lets you be a lot more precise with what you expose plus you can write a custom Java service bean to return the info...or use SSJS if you prefer.

Comment: Looks like that's the next step. DDS also sends all those weird @ markers which sometimes surprises the recipients. I've got an especially long bargepole specially for SSJS.

Answer (score 0):

You could look for the path in the catalog.nsf and get the application title from there.

Comment: I want to use REST though.